# Switch buffers in MacVim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, hotkeys, macvim

I want to be able to switch buffers (:bn! / :bp!) in MacVim, using shortcuts like

Alt (Option) - Left Arrow Key/Right Arrow Key

So far I wasn't able to do that.

Here's my mapping for the keys, which works perfectly fine in Linux, but not on MacOS:

```
map <M-Right> :bn!<CR>
map <M-Left> :bp!<CR>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim initialization files are processed in this order (simplified; see [`:help initialization`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#initialization*)):

1. `$VIM/vimrc`
2. `$HOME/.vimrc`
3. `$VIM/gvimrc`
4. `$HOME/.gvimrc`

The problem is that MacVim maps M-Right and M-Left (and several other key combinations) in its `$VIM/gvimrc` (i.e. `…/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc`); this will override any mappings you have made on those key combinations in `$HOME/.vimrc`.

If you examine this startup file (i.e. `:view $VIM/gvimrc`), you will find that these particular mappings can be inhibited by setting the special variable `macvim_skip_cmd_opt_movement` (to any value) in your `$HOME/.vimrc`.

```
let macvim_skip_cmd_opt_movement = 1
```

This will inhibit ten default MacVim mappings (Command and Option for each of Left, Right, Up, Down, and BS).

Alternatively, you could just put your mappings in your `$HOME/.gvimrc` (where they will override the default MacVim mappings even if you have not inhibited them with `macvim_skip_cmd_opt_movement`).

Comment: Chris, you are awesome!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try putting this in your .vimrc file:

```
" Set left and right option/alt keys to be meta keys
set macmeta
```

Then try those mappings again and see if they work. If you want to reverse it simply do `:set nomacmeta`.

If you also use this .vimrc file on computers without MacVim on them use this instead:

```
" Set left and right option/alt keys to be meta keys
if has("gui_macvim")
    set macmeta
endif
```

Comment: I get 'Invalid argument macmeta=rl' error message. If I do ':set macmeta rl' it turns all the text into right-to left view

Comment: Well you don't want to do ':set macmeta rl' because that is essentially two commands ':set macmeta' and ':set rl' (which you figured out does right to left text).

I realize I made a mistake in my original answer now (I couldn't test it because I don't have MacVim). I'll edit it, and see if the new solution works for you.

Comment: "set macmeta" unfortunately does not fix it, pressing alt-'->' just makes cursor jump to next word

Comment: Thanks for the has("gui_macvim") though!